# Automatic Network Discovery

Tags: network, us7543052

In reference to the patent: [US7543052](https://www.google.com/patents/US7543052)

So I have an idea for a networking application and I stumbled upon this patented document. I am not sure what the author is really patenting, would someone please explain it to me in the simplest terms what the author is patenting? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of the patent is defined by the claims. If you want to know what this patent protects, that is where you look.

I'll analyze the first caim as an example below.

> 1. An apparatus facilitating the monitoring of network traffic, comprising:
>      one or more network interfaces;
>
> a memory;
>
> a processor; and
>
> computer-executable program code stored in the memory and executable by the processor, the computer-executable program code comprising
>
> a traffic classification database module comprising computer-executable instructions configured, when executed, to cause the processor to
>   store at least one traffic class including a traffic class identifier and at least one attribute defining the traffic class;
>
> compare attributes stored in association with traffic class identifiers to attributes of a data flow to match a traffic class that corresponds to the data flow;
>
> a traffic discovery module comprising computer-executable instructions configured, when executed, to cause the processor to
>   discover new traffic classes associated with data flows for which the traffic classification database did not find a matching traffic class;
>   add discovered traffic classes to the traffic classification database after a discovery threshold has been exceeded;
>
> dynamically adjust under one or more computer program controls the discovery threshold based on a comparison of a current rate at which the discovered traffic classes are added to the traffic classification database to a threshold rate.

So the the first claim protects an "apparatus" (thats basically the same as saying something as everything could be an apparatus) that "facilitates" (means the apparatus could do what follows -> ergo "monitor network traffic")

comprising (means it has ALL of the following limitations)

memory, processor, program

where the program comprises:

a traffic classification database and a traffic discovery module.
What they do is explained in the claim too.

I know this claim sounds very generic, this is of course on purpose. Everything that is not explained further in the claim protects every thinkable way of doing this. So for example "at least one attribute defining the traffic class" can be everything. It could be the nameof the traffic class, the kind of traffic or any quantum entanglement nobody yet knows about that describes a traffic class.

Comment: The authors claim seems to be too abstract and general. Can you really patent these kinds of stuff? Does it mean that I cannot use the authors idea at all?

Comment: Yes and yes. You can check the prosecution history of the patent (thats the communication between applicant and examiner) at "Public Pair" or "espacenet" to see how much the claims got narrowed and what prior art was held against them. Then you will see how this patent distinguishes from that was known before.  Other than that, if what you want to use falls under the exact wording of one of the claims, you would be infringing the patent. If you want to use this in a startup for example, you could ask the company for a license, many license fees scale by sold devices, beeing cheap at the start

Comment: Other than that, you culd get an Non-Infringement-Opinion from a patent attorney (I'd say around 2-10k USD) which would most probably protect you from treble damages if you get sued later and the court decides against you. Or you could attack the patent (ex parte reexamination costs 7,5k flat USD I think)